# Power dissipated in transmission cable

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-engineering

Taken from NSAA/ENGAA 2022 (University of Cambridge's admissions assessments for  Natural Sciences/Engineering)

Electrical energy is transmitted at high voltage to a remote farm using an overhead power
cable. Each of the two wires in the cable has a resistance of 2.5Ω. The step-down transformer
in the farm has a voltage ratio of 5.0. The transformer is ideal and 100% efficient. It supplies a
power of 40kW to a resistive load at the farm at a voltage of 250V.
What is the rate at which electrical energy is transferred to thermal energy in the overhead
cable?

I have tried using a parallel wire method for this question, but this would give an effective resistance of 1.25 ohms. Using P = IV, I get a *total* current of 32A  as V_p = 250 x 5 = 1250V, I_p = P/V_p = (40,000/(1250)) which would imply 16A in each wire -> this gives either (32^2)*1.25 for effective resistance or (16^2)*(2.5)*(2 for the two wires). Both of these give 1.28kW, whereas the answer is 5.12kW. Does the question imply one wire is for transmission toward the transformer and the other is connected for the return path of the current (this seems to match up with the answer but goes against my interpretation for how the question is phrased)?

P.S. I also wondered if both wires would have 32A from I_p = 40,000/1250, but this would generate 80kW of total power to the secondary circuit (unless again I'm mistaken as to how these work). Sorry if there is anything unclear, I would appreciate anything to help my intuition.

Comment: How could parallel wires be used to carry energy? Are you thinking that the Earth is how the current returns to the power plant? So, to your "Does the question imply one wire is for transmission toward the transformer and the other is connected for the return path of the current?" the answer is yes. That is how most people would interpret the question to be, and how the examiner wanted the answer as.

Comment: Re, "32A...would imply 16A in each wire..." I suggest that you think about why the power is supplied by a _pair_ of wires. Why can't they just send all of the power down a single wire? Also, you could read about Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL) if that helps.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent the fact they mentioned a "cable" consisting of two wires suggested it could mean a cable of two wires in parallel that then wind around the transformer and return to the source. I did initially interpret the question as one forward and one back, but then someone asked me wouldn't the fact the cable comprises both mean they are both winding, I couldn't think of why not.

Comment: @SolomonSlow This may be a fundamental misunderstanding, but does a circuit need one wire to make contact with one end of a load and another with the other end, could you not just directly connect one (resistive) wire across the battery terminals? Even though I thought that is what the question meant by needing two wires, I couldn't see why you couldn't just have two wires in tandem winding back to the other battery terminal and a current losing energy due to resistive properties of those wires. Essentially, do we need some battery>contact wire>load>contact wire>(back to) battery set-up?

Comment: The answer is yes, to your question that you posed to SolomonSlow

Comment: @DanielWilliamsRuiz, Your one resistive wire makes _two_ connections with the battery—one to each terminal. If you want the one resistive wire to generate its heat at a location that is remote from the battery, then you will need a less-resistive transmission line consisting of _two_ wires between it and the battery. One of the two halves of the transmission line must connect one end of the resistance wire to the '-' end of the battery, and the other half connects the other end of the resistance wire to the '+' end of the battery.

Comment: Thank you both, that's what I thought originally, but second-guessed my understanding. This has been enlightening.